# Meteor - Helper inserting data duplicates into a collection every time I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm having a problem trying to implement notifications in meteor. I have this code inside a helper. It works correctly and gives the current user the right notifications for what they have subscribed to. However whenever I refresh the page the same notification is inserted twice into the notifications collection showing the user duplicates of the same notification in the ui. Anyone one know how to fix this?

```
Template.notifications.helpers({

  notifications : function(){

    Meteor.subscribe('theNotificationStatus');
    Meteor.subscribe('theNotificationSubscriptions');

    var currentUserID = Meteor.userId();
    var usersEventIds =  Subscriptions.find({userID: currentUserID}, {"eventID": 1});
    var userCategorys = Subscriptions.find({userID: currentUserID}, {"category": 1});
    var arrayEvents = [];
    var arrayCategory =[];

    usersEventIds.forEach(function (collection) {
      arrayEvents.push(collection.eventID);
  });

  userCategorys.forEach(function (collection) {
    arrayCategory.push(collection.category);
});

//All the status's the user should be notified for based on what eventID and categorys he/she is subscribed to.
  var userNotifications = Status.find( { $and: [ { eventID: { $in: arrayEvents  } } , { category: { $in: arrayCategory } } ] } );

//Putting all these status's into a notifications collection.

  userNotifications.forEach(function (collection) {

    var eventID = collection.eventID;
    var category = collection.category;
    var eventName = collection.currentEventName;

    Meteor.call('insertNotificationsData', eventID,category,eventName,currentUserID);
});

Meteor.subscribe('theNotifications');
return Notifications.find({currentUserID:currentUserID});

}

});
```

Comment: Helpers should be free of side-effects. They should read and return data - __NOT__ insert/update/modify the database. We have this rule because, as you found, helpers can run at unpredictable times. See the "Overworked Helpers" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) fore more information.

Comment: Is there anyway to over come this? Just as a temporary solution.